# how to store an encryption secret key safely

Tags: encryption, aes

I was asked at work to protect sensitive data that is kept into a Mysql Database. This database contains several tables, among which one has critical data that should ONLY be accessed using an API which is done in Django. To this API there will be only a certain number of people that will have access to it, so they will be the only persons able to access the data from this table.

So, the problem for the moment is that everybody has access to the database and to this table, so we decided to encrypt all data from this table using AES, with the aid of AES_ENCRYPT() and AES_DECRYPT() functions (according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html).

So.... up to this point everything is ok, but the main problem is how to store the AES key used for encryption/decryption.
After some brainstorming with my colleagues and google, I found that the best thing to do would be to use a Key Wrapper (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_Wrap), which consists in encrypting the original key (the master key) using keys that belong to the persons that can access this API that interacts with the database table. So, I was thinking about encrypting this key using the public key of each  person's public key that has access to this API, and store the encrypted version into a table that anyone can access. And then, when a user needs the master key, he/she only needs to retrieve the encrypted key, decrypt it with his/her private key, and finally he/she will have the key into the login session so they will be able to use it via the API.

I just want to know if there are better alternatives for this.

Comment: First you need to ask yourself why everyone is allowed to access this data. Have you considered using the [GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) instruction?

Comment: It doesn't work like that. I have very clear orders and there are constraints to be taken into account. This does not depend on me.... it's just how it is....my job is to make sure that only the authorized persons will be able to access the sensitive data.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for [IT security](http://security.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

The approach of using one key to encrypt content ("content encryption key," or *CEK*), then encrypting *that* key with the key of each authorized recipient ("key encryption key," or *KEK*) is a good one, and it's used in a number of standard protocols like S/MIME, PGP, etc.

*But:* in this environment, where will you store the private keys for authorized users? How will you keep them private?

Feasibility depends on your application, but it might be better to use a symmetric algorithm to encrypt the CEK for each user. Whenever that user wants to access the CEK, they have to re-enter their password so that the server never stores their key in the clear.